# LabVIEW Inserting/overwriting text into existing string

Tags: labview

I was wondering if folks have found a reliable way to inject text into an existing string.  Some context, I'm writing data to a string indicator formatted like a table, and I wanted to inject values into so they maintain a specific format, spacing-wise.  Writing to a table would definitely be easier, however I am porting a legacy program and wanted to provide familiarity to the end user.

Essentially, I want to do the equivalent of typing into a .txt file with the INSERT function enabled, where it just overwrites the content already in the string.  Example below (dashes added to show spacing) of how it is currently looking when I inject the values with hard coded spacing:

```
Time---value---avg. value---result
60------10---------20---------PASS
120------11---------20---------PASS
180------9---------15---------FAIL
```

I'd prefer it to look more lined up, like below:

```
Time---value---avg. value---result
60------10---------20---------PASS
120-----11---------20---------PASS
180-----9--------- 15---------FAIL
```

Writing my application using LabVIEW 2019

Edit: Header will obviously not change, only each subsequent line where the values can result in entries not looking lined up

Comment: I'd recommend to select a bit different approach. Keep your data internally as 2D array, and create subVI which will format it to string (as table). Keep there logic, which will align text nicely. But when you'll need to update value in the table - replace value in 2D array, and then display that 2D array with formatting. Code will be easier, and cleaner with such approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about "Replace Substring" function (https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/replace_substring/)? Doesn't it meet your requirements?

The diagram below outputs `01234999990123PASS890123456789`. The values of the integer and the word PASS are added replacing characters in the existing string, exactly like overstrike would do.

[image: diagram showing Replace Substring]